# Error to install epson L375 driver on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, printing, scanner, epson

I am trying to install the drivers and printer utilities of an epson L375 in ubuntu 16.04, but when I run the command to install the drivers an error occurs

```
 sudo dpkg -i epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.6.18-1lsb3.2_i386.deb
```

**Error**

```
(Leyendo la base de datos ... 298247 ficheros o directorios instalados actualmente.)
Preparando para desempaquetar epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.6.18-1lsb3.2_i386.deb ...
Desempaquetando epson-inkjet-printer-escpr:i386 (1.6.18-1lsb3.2) sobre (1.6.18-1lsb3.2) ...
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de epson-inkjet-printer-escpr:i386:
epson-inkjet-printer-escpr:i386 depende de lsb (>= 3.2).

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete epson-inkjet-printer-escpr:i386 (--install):
problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar
Procesando disparadores para libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
epson-inkjet-printer-escpr:i386
```

i tried to install dependecies **lsb**

```
sudo apt install lsb
```

but they are already installed

```
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
lsb ya está en su versión más reciente (9.20160110ubuntu0.2).
0 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 0 no actualizados.
```

how to solve this problem and install the requested dependencies and I have installed the latest update ubuntu 16.04 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem, the version of the driver that you download is for Ubuntu 16.04 of 32 bits you should download the version for 64 bits

**version 32 bits**

```
sudo dpkg -i epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.6.18-1lsb3.2_i386.deb
```

**version 64 btis**

```
sudo dpkg -i epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.6.18-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb
```